# Give www-data permissions of root?

Tags: 12.04, apache2, php, cron

I want to access the root crontab from web interface.I have Apache and PHP installed.I have a project in which i have to change the job timings in crontab.

How can i change the timing of crontab jobs from web interface? And how to configure permissions? 
If it is simple to do that from php function plz help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just run Apache as root. Or perhaps have your root crontab execute a file editable by www-data. Or add www-data to sudoers with no password.

Really no matter how you do it, it's just a really, really, really bad idea. There are all sorts of precautions built in to the OS to prevent you from doing exactly what you're saying because it completely strips away all the separation provided by the OS.

If www-data can edit root's crontab, then any web app can run any command as root. Full stop. The degree to which this is a bad idea is about as severe as it gets.

Don't do it.

Comment: I am using Apache in a Docker container and don't give a rat's a$$ about security crap because the container runs as root by default. But #$@#&* Apache runs under www-data which is useless because in a Docker container EVERYTHING is owned by root. In general bad idea to do what is asked but there are legit use cases where it is NECESSARY.